# PIL: Thumbnail and end up with a square image

Tags: python, png, thumbnails, python-imaging-library, alpha

Calling

```
image = Image.open(data)
image.thumbnail((36,36), Image.NEAREST)
```

will maintain the aspect ratio. But I need to end up displaying the image like this:

```
<img src="/media/image.png" style="height:36px; width:36px" />
```

Can I have a letterbox style with either transparent or white around the image?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Paste the image into a transparent image with the right size as a background

```
from PIL import Image
size = (36, 36)
image = Image.open(data)
image.thumbnail(size, Image.LANCZOS)
background = Image.new('RGBA', size, (255, 255, 255, 0))
background.paste(
    image, (int((size[0] - image.size[0]) / 2), int((size[1] - image.size[1]) / 2))
)
background.save("output.png")
```

EDIT: fixed syntax error

Comment: UPDATE: use `Image.ANTIALIAS` instead of `Image.NEAREST` to get more quality and compressed image.

Comment: **NOTE**: Be sure to use `background.save()` and *not* `image.save()`

Comment: For Python 3 replace "/" with "//"

Comment: @Babu: `Image.ANTIALIAS` was deprecated in favor of `Image.LANCZOS` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76616042/attributeerror-module-pil-image-has-no-attribute-antialias). I updated the answers but cannot edit your comment.

Answer (score 168):

PIL already has a function to do exactly that:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
thumb = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.LANCZOS)
```

Comment: It was 2 years later... ;) This is a good answer for the question, the older answer is good to have too, in case you want to do something similar but not quite the same

Comment: Sorry for the double post. For the sake of completeness: the first line above should read "from PIL import Image, ImageOps". (Assuming no other relevant imports elsewhere in the code.)

Comment: This method somehow cropping my image to fit into the resolution.

Comment: That method does not apply transparency in my case. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Using this method does *NOT* produce a square image with transparent padding.

Comment: Why so many upvotes? This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: it gets lots of upvotes because this question comes up high in a Google search for `python pil resize and crop` and this is an elegant solution for that, its irrelevance to the OP notwithstanding.

Comment: Or `python PIL center image square`, but this seem to crop it, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

```
from PIL import Image

import StringIO

def thumbnail_image():
    image = Image.open("image.png")
    image.thumbnail((300, 200))
    thumb_buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
    image.save(thumb_buffer, format=image.format)
    fp = open("thumbnail.png", "w")
    fp.write(thumb_buffer.getvalue())
    fp.close()
```

Comment: `thumbnail` won't force a square image.  And what is the point of using `StringIO`?

Answer (score 2):

Update of [Cesar Canassa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8469920/2351696).

This will create a thumbnail of `image.jpg` as `image_thumb.jpg`:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
fname = 'image.jpg'
size = (48,48)
thumb = ImageOps.fit(Image.open(fname), size, Image.LANCZOS)
thumb.save('{}_thumb.jpg'.format(fname[:fname.rfind('.')]), "JPEG")
```

Answer (score 1):

Or this, maybe... (forgive spaghetti)

```
from PIL import Image

def process_image(image, size):
    if image.size[0] > size[0] or image.size[1] > size[1]:
        #preserve original
        thumb = image.copy()
        thumb.thumbnail(size,Image.LANCZOS)
        img = thumb.copy()
    img_padded = Image.new("RGBA",size)
    img_padded.paste(image,(int((size[0]-image.size[0])/2),int((size[1]-image.size[1])/2)))
    return img_padded
```

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap Nadia's answer in this function, which gives you control over size and background.

```
def make_square(im, min_size=36, fill_color=(255, 255, 255, 0)):
    x, y = im.size
    size = min(min_size, x, y)
    new_im = Image.new('RGBA', (size, size), fill_color)
    im.thumbnail((256, 256))
    new_im.paste(im, (int((x - size) / 2), int((y -size) / 2))
    return new_im
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use the resize method ?

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('/path/to/img.png')
image = image.resize((36,36), Image.LANCZOS)
```

See recommendations for image resizing in this release note:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/5.3.0.html

Comment: Because it squishes the image.