# Create thumbnail images for jpegs with python

Tags: python, image-processing

As the title says i am looking for a way convert a huge number of images into thumbnails of different sizes , How do i go about doing this in python

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See: http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/index.htm

```
import os, sys
import Image

size = 128, 128

for infile in sys.argv[1:]:
    outfile = os.path.splitext(infile)[0] + ".thumbnail"
    if infile != outfile:
        try:
            im = Image.open(infile)
            im.thumbnail(size)
            im.save(outfile, "JPEG")
        except IOError:
            print "cannot create thumbnail for", infile
```

Comment: If you need it to be a square thumbnail regardless of the original image's aspect ratio, then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386352/pil-thumbnail-and-end-up-with-a-square-image.

Comment: **Update (2020)**: `from PIL import Image`, see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pillow/python_pillow_creating_thumbnails.htm