# How I can thumbnail an image with Python

Tags: python, image

I want to thumbnail an image with Python (resize it to small size).

How I can do this?
Do you know any library to do this work?

Comment: please google before ask question, you can use PIL library(Python Image Library)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create thumbnail images for jpegs with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612436/create-thumbnail-images-for-jpegs-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

‍‍‍Use PIL Library:
‌‌

```
‍‍
‍‍from PIL import Image
image = Image.open(full_image_loc)
image.thumbnail((360, 360), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image.save('thumbnail.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

or you can use Image class:

```
from PIL import Image
import glob, os

size = 128, 128

for infile in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
    im = Image.open(infile)
    im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    im.save(file + ".thumbnail", "JPEG")
```

Comment: thank's, I need to same this code.

Comment: the link is obselete now

Answer (score 3):

A very quick Google search immediately returned [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio):

```
size = 128, 128

try:
    im = Image.open(infile)
    im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    im.save(outfile, "JPEG")
except IOError:
    print "cannot create thumbnail for '%s'" % infile
```

The search terms I used were `PIL`, `Python`, `resize`, and `image`. You could also try `thumbnail`. The Python Imaging Library (`PIL`) is the tool you will want to use for this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use PIL (the Python Image Library)

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open(full_image_loc)
image.thumbnail((360, 360), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image.save('thumbnail.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

You'll also need to figure out how to install PIL...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) image module for Python. It should allow you to easily create a thumbnail.

There is even a very simple example on their page:

```
from PIL import Image
import glob, os

size = 128, 128

for infile in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
    im = Image.open(infile)
    im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    im.save(file + ".thumbnail", "JPEG")
```

Comment: As mentioned. Please, put some effort into your questions. Otherwise you are likely to not get help with future problems. Take a look at the http://stackoverflow.com/about section for more information on how to ask questions properly.