# AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'ANTIALIAS'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

- I am trying to have images in my Tkinter GUI, hence I am using [PIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library).
- *Image.ANTIALAIS* is not working. However, *Image.BILINEAR* works

Here's some sample code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window = tk.Tk()

image = Image.open(r"VC.png")
image = image.resize((20, 20), Image.ANTIALIAS)

tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

image_label = tk.Label(window, image=tk_image)
image_label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 19, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'ANTIALIAS'
```

- I tried reinstalling pip *and* [Pillow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library). It didn't work.
- I asked [ChatGPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChatGPT) about this, and it advised me to upgrade to Pillow's latest version. I am on the latest version (10.0.0).

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why do you think that there should be an attribute `ANTIALIAS`?

Comment: Backwards compatibility is so 1960 style when IBM had to learn the lesson badly :-)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

`ANTIALIAS` was removed in Pillow 10.0.0 (after being deprecated through many previous versions). Now you need to use `PIL.Image.LANCZOS` or `PIL.Image.Resampling.LANCZOS`.

(This is the exact same algorithm that `ANTIALIAS` referred to, you just can no longer access it through the name `ANTIALIAS`.)

Reference: [Pillow 10.0.0 release notes (with table of removed constants)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/10.0.0.html#constants)

---

Simple code example:

```
import PIL
import numpy as np

# Gradient image with a sharp color boundary across the diagonal
large_arr = np.fromfunction(lambda x, y, z: (x+y)//(z+1),
                            (256, 256, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
large_img = PIL.Image.fromarray(large_arr)

# Resize it: PIL.Image.LANCZOS also works here
small_img = large_img.resize((128, 128), PIL.Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
print(small_img.size)

large_img.show()
small_img.show()
```

Comment: `pip install Pillow==9.5.0` workaround for old code.

Comment: an example of code would help, I still have the error with Image.Resampling.LANCZOS

Comment: See edit. If you still have issues, you could post a question stating the PIL version and the error message you get.

Comment: I like how the abbreviation LANCZOS forces users to visit stackoverflow - very good marketing for the platform by the Pillow folks! ChatGPT will not guess this with it's 2021 cut-off time. We need to do more things to confuse users and ChatGPT!

Comment: Ig the Pillow folks are in partnership with Stackoverflow at this point. Cuz I am seeing a lot of errors coming up. XD

Comment: I have added this in the first py script, to work around the issue. maybe it helps someone:
```import PIL
PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS = PIL.Image.LANCZOS```

Comment: @gamingflexer while your answer may be helpful also note that every version less than 10.x is vulnerable to [CVE-2023-4863](https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-PYTHON-PILLOW-5918878) published on [libwebp](https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-UNMANAGED-WEBMPROJECTLIBWEBP-5918283)

Answer (score 13):

In [EasyOCR](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR), the following error appeared:

```
img = cv2.resize(img, (int(model_height*ratio), model_height), interpolation=Image.ANTIALIAS)AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'ANTIALIAS'
```

I did the following:

```
pip uninstall Pillow
pip install Pillow==9.5.0
```

The problem must be with Pillow version 10.0.

Comment: After downgrading the Pillow version to 9.5.0, I got the following error from numpy package. (I did not use this package anywhere in my code)

Answer (score 12):

The problem is with [Pillow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library) 10.0.

Trying to uninstall Pillow might give some errors.

Just put this in cmd:

`pip install Pillow==9.5.0`

Comment: Or just use `Image.LANCZOS`

Answer (score 4):

Hacky way but worked:

In the utils.py file of `easyOCR/Scripts`, I replaced the `ANTIALIAS` with `LANCZOS`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This will work only for your specific machine. It would throw an error when distributing the code. 
So when your manager asks why it didn't work on the client's machine, just say "It works on my machine " XD

Answer (score 4):

You can add the below before your code as a quick patch.

```
from PIL import Image as pil
from pkg_resources import parse_version

if parse_version(pil.__version__)>=parse_version('10.0.0'):
    Image.ANTIALIAS=Image.LANCZOS
```

Answer (score 3):

ANTIALIAS is deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 (2023-07-01). Use LANCZOS or Resampling.LANCZOS instead.

Answer (score 3):

Downgrading using pip worked for me:

```
pip3 install "Pillow<10.0.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply replaced my line `img.thumbnail(output_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)` with `img.thumbnail(output_size, Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)` and it worked.

This issue started from Pillow 7.0 release.